# button img not showing

Tags: css, image, button, position

Sorry for my beginner question.
My image is not showing, but I do not know why. I have tried 'background-position: center;' and with 'px' values as well. The only way I can see my image if I delete 'no-repeate', but than it fills my box with hundrends of arrows. Any suggestion? I need the image only once in the center of the box.

```html
<input id="leftBigArrow" type="button">
```

```css
#leftBigArrow {
    width: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background-image: url('images/arrow.svg') no-repeat;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `no-repeat` and `url('images/arrow.svg')` separately with

```css
background-image: url('images/arrow.svg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Or you can use the shorthand:

```css
background: url('images/arrow.svg') no-repeat;
```

**Working example:**

```css
#leftBigArrow {
    width: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/50');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="leftBigArrow" type="button">
```

Comment: thank you. very fast and helpful community

Comment: If that answers your question you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this property.

```
#leftBigArrow {
 background-position : center;
 background-attachment : fixed;
}
```